# Writing a csv file, with corresponding category in column 2 using Python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

Expected output is CSV file with production description in column 1.

The code sample below outputs CSV file with product description in column 2.

```
#function to return the results i.e. categorize the sentence  
def categorize(sentence, show_details=False):
    results = think(sentence)
    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>error_threshold ] 
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
    return_results =[classes[r[0]] for r in results]
    return return_results

# code to write csv file, with the corresponding category of product in column 2
import itertools
a=[]
g=open('test1.csv','r+')
reader=csv.reader(g)
for i in itertools.product(*reader):
    for j in range(0,len(i)):
        a.append(categorize(i[j]))
writer=csv.writer(g)
writer.writerows(a)
g.close()
# the output shuld look like:
# iphone          Mobile
# skipping rope   sports'
```

Comment: Show a sample of `sentence`. You tried to read and write to the same file, this will fail. I consider to read the `csv` document.

Comment: sentence is a simple string...nothing special... Yes, I have considered reading csv document separately and it worked ...Thanks.

Comment: Summarized problem as actual/expected results, fixed indentation in code sample